# Meaning of two solutions to $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I understand that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

Does that mean that $\sin(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$?

Specifically: I don't understand the meaning of the $\pm$ sign: what is the difference between the positive and the negative solution?

How to know what solution to pick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the plotted function and compare that to sin(x) we can quickly see that $\sqrt{1-cos^2(x)}$ is actually the absolute value of sin(x), so the $\pm$ indicates that it's sometimes + and sometimes - rather than both.
[image]
Red  - $\sqrt{1-cos^2(x)}$

Blue - $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ whereas $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: That's not really relevant.

Comment: The sine identity is somewhat relevant, though the OP probably needs the relevance to be spelled out. I do not see any relevance for the cosine identity. Could you improve this answer?

Answer (score 0):

To make things clear, let us review some of the different equations one can have for the unit circle:

It can be represented by a set of 2 parametric equations $x=\cos(t),y=\sin(t)$.

which give rise to an implicit equation $x^2+y^2=1$, which itself yields equivalently to a set of 2 cartesian equations :

$y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for the upper part, $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ fir the lower part (below the x-axis).